# What causes this server error of a newly created next.js app?

Tags: next.js

I created a new next.js app using `npx create-next-app@latest foo`.

When I navigate my browser to `http://localhost:3000/`, I get a response from the server, but the next.js start page does not show up.

Instad I get:

```
Server Error

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:32837

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
<unknown>
error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1 (44587)
<unknown> (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
127.0.0.1 (44587)
TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]
node:net (1532:16)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

---

I am on Linux, btw.

This is what the terminal shows:

```
$ npm run dev

> foo@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
event - compiled client and server successfully in 4.8s (170 modules)
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1315 ms (199 modules)
error - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:44587
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1532:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 44587
}
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 128 ms (200 modules)
```